# $3x^2-12x+m$ is negative for all values of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question says that find the range of value of $m$ for which the function $3x^2-12x+m$ is negative for all values of $x$

My attempt,

$b^2-4ac<0$

$(-12)^2-4(3)(m)<0$

$144-12m<0$

$m>12$

But the given answer is $m<12$. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the question is not "for what values of m the equation attains negative values" because watch the coefficient of $x^{2}$ its positive its supposed to be a upward parabola . So it will have positive values anyhow .

Comment: So now since we know it will be an upward parabola the equation must have real roots so that some portion of the curve will lie possibly below X axis . Hence $b^{2}-4ac>0$

Comment: Could the question be "find the range of value of mm for which the function is negative for *some* value of $x$"? I ask, because the parabola opens up, so it *must* be positive at some point. But $m$ must be less than 12 for it to *ever* be negative.

Comment: Why did you use b^2-4ac<0???

Answer (score 1):

From this [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3x%5E2+-12x+%2B+12), it is clear that by having $m>12$, we will have no real solutions, and no negative values for the function at any point $x$.

I think the question might be poorly written, and it could be asking, for which values of $m$, can the function attain negative values. This would give you $m < 12$.

Answer (score 0):

$b^2-4ac<0$ means that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has no real solution, that is, $ax^2+bx+c\ne 0, \forall x.$ Since your parabola opens up, you have that $3x^2-12x+m$ is always positive under your assumption.

So, if you are interested into $ax^2+bx+c$ being negative for some $x,$ you need $b^2-4ac>0,$ since your parabola opens up. In such a case, you get $m<12.$

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your proof for $b^2-4ac>0$, instead of for $b^2-4ac<0$, you will obtain the desired result.

What you have discovered is values for $m$, that provide real roots.

Since the parabola is curved upwards, it will *always* be positive for *some* value of $x$. However, by finding the range of $m$ that produces a function with real roots, you've found the forms of this parabola that dip below the $x$-axis. You've found values of $m$ that produces *some* negative values for *y*.

(I question the wording of the question here. Is this *exactly* how it's posed in the textbook, or wherever this question came from?)

You can play with this function [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/36kz9bmymw). Try moving the $m$ slider and see what happens to the parabola.

Here's a snapshot where $m=12$.

[image: parabola where m=12]